# Programmatic Object Creation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, object, initialization, implementation, alloc

Below there are two methods to programmatically `alloc` and `init` objects of various classes and 'types'.

```
- (id)buildObjectOfClass:(NSString *)classString andType:(NSString *)typeString
    {
    id buildObject;
    Class className             = NSClassFromString(classString);
    SEL initWithTypeSelector    = NSSelectorFromString(@"initWithType:");

    if ([className instancesRespondToSelector:initWithTypeSelector] == YES) {
        buildObject = [[className alloc] performSelector:initWithTypeSelector 
                                              withObject: typeString];
    }
    return buildObject;
}
```

This method implementation was originally written more tersely as simply:
`{ return [[className alloc] initWithType:typeString]; }`

 My questions are: 1) is the verbose version necessary? and 2) if so, was it programmed as best as it could be?  Are there shortcuts or best practices I am neglecting?

Comment: Can you explain the *why* of this? I can't think of a single instance where I would ever want to do this. You're opening yourself up to a lot of errors/crashes by building classes and selectors from strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the verbose and terse versions of this method are that the verbose version validates that the class instances can actually respond to `-initWithType:` which is not a standard `NSObject` init function.

It is unnecessary to use the verbose version if any of the following were true:

- You are only using `-init` and not `-initWithType:`
- You are certain that every class you instantiate will be able to handle `-initWithType:`
- You don't mind the application unexpectedly quitting with an unknown method exception if the  class you instantiate does not respond to `-initWithType:`

This version (although you should set `buildObject` to nil to handle the error case explicitly) returns `nil` if the class isn't found or if it doesn't respond to `-initWithType:`.    The terse version returns `nil` if the class isn't found and throws an exception if the class instances don't respond to `-initWithType:`.

Comment: The long version returns `nil` when the `respondsToSelector:` check fails _only_ when compiling under ARC. Otherwise it returns garbage.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I believe I made a specific reference to that fact at the start of my final paragraph.

Comment: I was replying directly to that. That sentence reads to me as if you're saying that `buildObject` will always be `nil` if the instance does not respond to `initWithType:`. That's not true if ARC is not enabled.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Specifically: `although you should set buildObject to nil to handle the error case explicitly` is what I'm talking about. It's true that I don't specifically call out ARC vs non-ARC, but it's bad form regardless in any C-variant language to return an uninitialized value.

Comment: Yes, we agree about that practice. What I'm saying is that your statement «This version ... returns `nil` if the class isn't found or if it doesn't respond to `-initWithType:`.» is _not correct_ without including ARC as a condition. ARC initializes object variables to `nil`; without it they are like any other stack variable and point to junk. And this is exactly _why_ it should be initialized manually.